# How to fix Chart js Bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chart.js

i make a bar with chart js in a project with next but the bar is stick on left panel[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aZWe.png)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import BarChart from './Graphics/BarChart';
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import styles from '@styles/pages/statistics/Statistics.module.css';
import PieChart from './Graphics/PieChart';
import BarKPIChart from './Graphics/BarKPIChart';
import BarChartByTags from './Graphics/BarChartByTags';
import { useAnswersStatistic } from '@hooks/Answers/useAnswersStatistics';

export default function ChartToShow(props) {
  const [componentToRender, setComponentToRender] = useState(null);
  const { stateAnswer } = useAnswersStatistic();
  const { questionsAnswers } = stateAnswer;
  useEffect(() => {
    let component;
    switch (props.componentType) {
      case 'Pie':
        component = <PieChart questionsAnswers={questionsAnswers} idQuestion={props.idQuestion} />;
        break;
      case 'Bar':
        component = <BarChart questionsAnswers={questionsAnswers} idQuestion={props.idQuestion} />;
        break;
      case 'BarKPI':
        component = <BarKPIChart questionsAnswers={questionsAnswers} idQuestion={props.idQuestion} />;
        break;
      case 'BarTag':
        component = <BarChartByTags questionsAnswers={questionsAnswers} idQuestion={props.idQuestion} />;
        break;
    }
    setComponentToRender(component);
  }, [props.componentType, questionsAnswers, props.idQuestion]);

  return <Container className={styles.chart_wrapper}>{componentToRender}</Container>;
}
```

```
import { Chart as ChartJS, Tooltip, Legend, CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, PointElement, LineElement, LineController, BarController, ArcElement } from 'chart.js';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import 'dayjs/locale/es';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

ChartJS.register(ArcElement, LinearScale, CategoryScale, BarElement, PointElement, LineElement, Legend, Tooltip, LineController, BarController, ChartDataLabels);

export default function BarChartByTags({ questionsAnswers, idQuestion }) {
  const dataToShow = questionsAnswers.find((item) => item.id === idQuestion);
  const length_question = dataToShow?.data?.length;
  const getColors = (number) => {
    if (number == 5) {
      return ['#3ec200', '#379d07', '#BCBCBC', '#ef812e', '#ff0000'];
    } else if (number == 4) {
      return ['#3ec200', '#379d07', '#ef812e', '#ff0000'];
    } else if (number == 7) {
      return ['#3ec200', '#379d07', '#379d07', '#BCBCBC', '#ef812e', '#ef812e', '#ff0000'];
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  };
  function dosDecimales(n) {
    let t = n.toString();
    let regex = /(\d*.\d{0,2})/;
    return t.match(regex)[0];
  }

  const colors = getColors(length_question);
  const labels = [];
  const total = [];
  dataToShow?.labels?.forEach((element) => {
    labels.push(dayjs(element).locale('es').format('DD MMM'));
    total.push(0);
  });
  const graphic = {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        label: '',
        borderColor: '#14140A',
        borderWidth: 2,
        fill: false,
        data: [],
        datalabels: {
          labels: {
            title: null,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  };
  total.forEach((element, index) => {
    dataToShow?.data?.forEach((item) => {
      total[index] += parseInt(item.data[index]);
    });
  });
  dataToShow?.data?.forEach((item, index) => {
    const dataBar = [];
    const dataset = {
      type: 'bar',
      label: String,
      backgroundColor: colors[index],
      borderColor: colors[index],
      fill: false,
      data: [],
      stack: 'stack 0',
      barPercentage: 0.5,
      datalabels: {
        color: 'black',
        formatter: function (value, context) {
          return Math.round((parseInt(value) / 100) * total[context.dataIndex]);
        },
      },
    };
    item.data.forEach((elemento, indexItem) => {
      const number = (parseInt(elemento) * 100) / total[indexItem];
      dataBar.push(dosDecimales(number));
    });
    dataset.label = item.buttontext;
    dataset.data = dataBar;
    if (index == 0) {
      graphic.datasets[0].data = dataBar;
    }
    graphic.datasets.push(dataset);
  });
  return <Chart data={graphic} />;
}
```

**Structure of questionsAnswers**

```
{
  questionsAnswers: [
    {
      data: [
        {
          data: []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      question: '<p>Ej. ¿En una escala de caras, que tan satisfecho quedó?</p>',
      labels: [
        '2023-06-07T04:00:00.000Z'
      ],
      data: [
        {
          buttontext: 'Muy Satisfecho',
          range: 'Satisfechos',
          data: [
            '2'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Satisfecho',
          range: 'Satisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Insatisfecho',
          range: 'Insatisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Muy Insatisfecho',
          range: 'Insatisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      question: '<p>Ej. ¿En una escala de caras, que tan satisfecho quedó?</p>',
      labels: [
        '2023-06-07T04:00:00.000Z'
      ],
      data: [
        {
          buttontext: 'Muy Satisfecho',
          range: 'Satisfechos',
          data: [
            '2'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Satisfecho',
          range: 'Satisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Insatisfecho',
          range: 'Insatisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Muy Insatisfecho',
          range: 'Insatisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      question: '<p>Ej. ¿En una escala de caras, que tan satisfecho quedó?</p>',
      labels: [
        '2023-06-07T04:00:00.000Z'
      ],
      data: [
        {
          buttontext: 'Muy Satisfecho',
          range: 'Satisfechos',
          data: [
            '2'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Satisfecho',
          range: 'Satisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Insatisfecho',
          range: 'Insatisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Muy Insatisfecho',
          range: 'Insatisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      question: '<p>Ej. ¿En una escala de caras, que tan satisfecho quedó?</p>',
      labels: [
        '2023-06-07T04:00:00.000Z'
      ],
      data: [
        {
          buttontext: 'Muy Satisfecho',
          range: 'Satisfechos',
          data: [
            '2'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Satisfecho',
          range: 'Satisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Insatisfecho',
          range: 'Insatisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Muy Insatisfecho',
          range: 'Insatisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      question: '<p>Ej. ¿En una escala de caras, que tan satisfecho quedó?</p>',
      labels: [
        '2023-06-07T04:00:00.000Z'
      ],
      data: [
        {
          buttontext: 'Muy Satisfecho',
          range: 'Satisfechos',
          data: [
            '2'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Satisfecho',
          range: 'Satisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Insatisfecho',
          range: 'Insatisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        },
        {
          buttontext: 'Muy Insatisfecho',
          range: 'Insatisfechos',
          data: [
            '1'
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

props.quiestionId is id of question to find in the array

the graph mush be like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZHZw.png)
but this hapens when i change some in code and the chart re-renderize

Comment: The error is probably in the component you're using, e.g., `BarChart`. Please add the code for that, as well as the structure of `questionsAnswers` and the value of `props.idQuestion`. Ideally, you should post a runnable example, like a forkable codesandbox or stackblitz.